# Android Bug: App running overnight displays duplicate fragments(?) and crashes

Tags: android-fragments

I seem to get a bug. When FragmentB is displayed and has been overnight and then in the morning when I open the app FragmentA is displayed first. When I hit the back-button it seems like FragmentA disapiers however underneath it it appears another FragmentA is hiding. When I try to "use" the app normally again it crashes.

My app is working like wonders otherwise when I activley use it. The only difference is when I leave my phone for a large amount of time (when I sleep)

As I said I discovered this bug when I woke up this morning and was gonna test out my app again. I've tried to recreate my actions from last night and the app works perfect :/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to have something to do with Android's garbage collection. When your app is in the background and other processes are running, the garbage collection may delete your app's data or state, causing it to misbehave. This is especially true the longer the app spends running in the background.

Possible solutions:

- Do you save your app's state in the savedInstanceState bundle and load it back in the onRestoreInstanceState() method?
- If you think it might be an SQL error, you should save your variables so when your program resumes it can reload important values.

Some tips:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/track-memory-allocations.html

Comment: Thank you for the tips will look this up and get back to you!